# Adding print titles to a worksheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm unable to add print titles to my Excel worksheet using openpyxl. The named range is created properly but it doesn't properly become the named range for the print titles. The problem seems to be that the scope of the print titles named range is incorrect (at least, if I am understanding it correctly). Instead of the scope being the worksheet name as it is if I create print titles manually in Excel, the scope is always 'Workbook'. Here's a relevant snippet of the code I'm using:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.add_print_title(1, rows_or_cols='rows')
```

As far as I can tell `add_print_title` only needs the number of rows or columns to add to the named range and whether rows and columns are being added. And like I said, this creates a named range properly, it just doesn't make that named range into the print titles. Maybe I'm missing something silly, but I've exhausted all Google searches and my little bit of knowledge.

Comment: Found some things here: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html#Worksheet.add_print_title

Comment: and this is the docs for it: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html?highlight=add_print_title#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.add_print_title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to the test case your calling it correctly:

```
def test_print_titles():
    wb = Workbook()
    ws1 = wb.create_sheet()
    ws2 = wb.create_sheet()
    ws1.print_title_rows = '1:2'  # NOTE this was depricated, old code was ws1.add_print_title(2)
    ws2.print_title_cols = '1:3'  # NOTE: this replaces depricated add_print_title, code was ws2.add_print_title(3, rows_or_cols='cols')

    def mystr(nr):
        return ','.join(['%s!%s' % (sheet.title, name) for sheet, name in nr.destinations])

    actual_named_ranges = set([(nr.name, nr.scope, mystr(nr)) for nr in wb.get_named_ranges()])
    expected_named_ranges = set([('_xlnm.Print_Titles', ws1, 'Sheet1!$1:$2'),
                                 ('_xlnm.Print_Titles', ws2, 'Sheet2!$A:$C')])
    assert(actual_named_ranges == expected_named_ranges)
```

It seems it is a known issue right now, but there is a fix in place, so the next version should take care of it.  You can fix it now by editing the file yourself as shown here in this diff:

https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/pull-request/47/fix-issue-417-creating-print-titles/diff

Comment: just saw this. I actually submitted the fix you posted about -- should have updated here when I figured it out. Thanks for updating it here!

Comment: add_print_title has been deprecated as of 2.4.0. Instead, use print_title_rows or print_title_cols

Comment: thanks @Tom do you know what print_title_rows is? Is it just an array of rows?  I cound not find it in http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=add_print_title

Comment: @nycynik, There's an example [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/print_settings.html#add-print-titles), but it's not quite clear. The equivalent of `ws.add_print_title(3, 'rows')` would be `ws.print_title_rows = '1:3'`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how well we (can) support this as it seems to use stuff not covered in the specification. I've never used this method myself so I'm not that familiar with it.

Please submit a bug with two files: what openpyxl produces; what it should be.